# datetime.time(0, 0) evaluates as False in boolean context

Tags: python, datetime

(Python v3.4)

Can someone explain the logic behind this?

```
from datetime import (datetime, time,)

dt = datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0)
t1 = dt.time()

t1 or print("I'm False")
```

Prints I'm False.

Why would a non-None object evaluate as false? Isn't the time "00:00" valid?

Comment: No it does not they both print False

Comment: Oops, yes they do. Fixed the question to focus on the fact that an object evaluates as false. Sorry :-/

Comment: @klirion,  if the left side is  any falsey value then the right side will be executed

Comment: `0`, `[]`, `{}` etc. are all non-None objects, and they all evaluate to `False` - do you agree that that makes sense? If so, why should a "zero" time evaluate to `True`?

Comment: Letting alone the fact that there are valid arguments against even 0, [], {} being falsey, why on earth would time "00:00" be False?

Comment: changing your question after it has been answered is not really helpful

Comment: @Pradraic Cunningham It was really 2 questions. You didn't have to delete your post, I still upvoted it even though I did not agree with the content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug.  It [was fixed in 3.5](http://bugs.python.org/issue13936).  See [this article](http://lwn.net/Articles/590299/) for further discussion.

Comment: I was about to answer that it's false for the same reason that `bool(0)` is false. I'm glad this answer came up before I hit the submit button!